# iphone : facebook application responce error message

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, facebook

I am trying to integrate facebook in my iphone application. after logged in from my iphone I am getting  response message as "application responce error"

can any one help out , why I am getting such an error???

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes i've got the answer.

When you have made some changes in the facebook application that is registered with facebook, then the api key and secret keys are need to be refreshed i.e. it will be changed.

So face book will provide error "Application Response Error".

Just change the Api key and Secret key and the application will run.

hurray... I've done in ....